# What are the differences between KILL, SUSPEND and TERMINATE of a process

Tags: bash, process

What are the differences between

- `Kill` a process
- `Suspend` a process
- `Terminate` a process

In which situation is each term used.

Comment: Take a look at the "Related" column to the right, or read http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal

Comment: SIGTERM gracefully kills the process whereas SIGKILL kills the process immediately.
    SIGTERM signal can be handled, ignored and blocked but SIGKILL cannot be handled or blocked.
    SIGTERM doesn’t kill the child processes. SIGKILL kills the child processes as well.
https://linuxhandbook.com/sigterm-vs-sigkill/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To *suspend* a process means to make it stop executing for some time. When the process is suspended, it doesn't run, but it's still present in memory, waiting to be *resumed* (woken up). A process can be suspended by sending it the `STOP` signal, and resumed by sending it the `CONT` signal.

To *kill* a process means to cause it to die. This can be done by sending it a [signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal). There are various different signal, and they don't all cause the process to die. the `KILL` signal always does cause the process to die; some other signals typically do but the process can choose to do something different; and there are signals whose role is not to cause the process to die, for example `STOP` and `CONT`. Note that the `kill` utility and the `kill` C function send a signal, which may or may not actually kill the process.

To *terminate* a process means to cause it to die. The difference between *kill* and *terminate* is that *kill* generally refers specifically to sending a signal, whereas *terminate* usually also includes other methods such as sending the process a command that tells it to exit (if the process includes a command interpreter of some kind).

Comment: Noob related question: If I've got an SSH session going into a remote unit, and a process X going on the remote unit, will Ctrl-Z suspend process X, or the SSH session itself?

Comment: @brianfit The SSH client transmits Ctrl-Z to the server, so it will suspend process X. To suspend the OpenSSH client, type `~` (tilde) then Ctrl-Z at the beginning of a line.